For 4.2 Using F key to fill or connect the vertices or edges from two circle meshes?
I'm following a soda modelling tutorial but encounter a problem when I tried to click F key to on two selected vertices or edges it will only fill inside of the circle mesh, can you help me with this problem?



OK, so you told us what it does and that it's a problem, but you haven't actually said what you want to do. What is it that you want to do? If you want to connect the selected vertices, it only works on a mesh of a single object. You have 2 objects selected, so the vertices belong to 2 different objects. Merge the objects in object mode (ctrl+j), then try again. Is that what you want?

"OK, so you told us what it does and that it's a problem, but you haven't actually said what you want to do. What is it that you want to do? " I wanted to connect the vertices like adding edge to the selected vertices.  "it only works on a mesh of a single object. You have 2 objects selected, so the vertices belong to 2 different objects. Merge the objects in object mode (ctrl+j), then try again. Is that what you want?" I did that and actually work, I guess its not simple by clicking F key on selected two vertices or edges :(

Two objects have 2 different meshes that are stored separately, geometry between them cannot be connected while they are separate, that's just how it works. The ability to enter edit mode of multiple objects at the same time is actually a feature that wasn't always there. It brings a lot of convenience, but simply cannot work with all operations, because they must remain separate objects. This actually makes a lot of sense.

Thank you for the explanation.
